# chemical potential in zero bandwidt s-f model

Tags: condensed-matter, second-quantization, chemical-potential, ferromagnetism

I have to compute the chemical potential in the zero bandwidth s-f model, analized in  [this article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/pssb.2221230118), from the following condition
$$
n=\left\langle\hat{n}_{\uparrow}\right\rangle+\left\langle\hat{n}_{\uparrow}\right\rangle
$$
where $n$ is the band occupation while the average values are 
$$
\left\langle\hat{n}_{\sigma}\right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{4}\,\alpha_{i,\sigma}\,f_{i}\left(T\right),\quad \sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow
$$
and
$$
f_{i}\left(T\right)=\frac{1}{1 + \exp\left[\frac{\left(E_{i}-\mu\right)}{k_{B}\,T}\right]}
$$
is the Fermi-Dirac distribution.

In the ferromagnetic state $\left(T<T_{C}<100\,K\right)$, for the set of parameters choosed by the author's article, the energtic gaps are larger then $k_{B}\,T$ then the fermi functions deviates from 0 to 1, when the chemical potential $\mu$ is close to one of the leves $E_{i}$

If i assume it, how computations could be simplified ?

Comment: It is not clear why assuming that $T < T_C$ would make  Fermi-Dirac distributions independent on $\mu$. Could you formulate the question more clearly?

Comment: This is the question. I don't think that it should be idipendent, in fact the article's author obtain a relation for the chemical potential when the band occupation  n is <1 and another one when n>1 . But what he said in the article about the comparision between energetic gaps and kbT , let me think this.  I don't know how this could simplify computation.

Comment: What I mean is that FD distribution is explicitly dependent on $\mu$ and you are not making any approximations yet, so it is not clear what you mean by saying that it is *independent on $\mu$*.

Comment: Yes, but how can i use what he assumed in the computation of chemical potential?

Comment: You may try approximating the Fermi function by a step function, since the temperature is effectively zero. (Comment: The opposite limit is high temperatures, where it becomes a Boltzmann distribution.)

Comment: By doing this the dipendence on the chemical potential is in conditions where the fermi dirac distribution is 1 or 0, not in the expressions, then how can i compute its value?

Comment: I do not think it makes difference whether it is in the conditions or the expression - it will enter your final equations. Also, conditions can be written as an expression using a step function: $1/(1+e^{(E-\mu)/(k_BT)})\rightarrow \theta(\mu-E)$.

A remark: aren't you supposed to have a band of finite width and integration over the energies somewhere?

Comment: Thank you, i try again and i hopento find the article's equation. The case of finite bandwidth it is treated in the alloy anology , this article did not treat it.

Comment: Replacing it with the step function i did not obtain a temperature dependence, that it is showed in eq (3.3) of linked article.